# BIRT expression to surround negative numbers with brackets

Tags: birt

I have a number of birt reports with conditional highlighting of negative numbers. So if the number is negative I highlight the numbers in red. What I would also like to do is to replace the negative indicator with brackets around the number but am not sure how to do that. i.e. the numbers you see in red in the screen shot below would still be red but htey should also be enclosed in breackets...

(285)
(629)
(18.73)
(20)
(95)
(45)
(75)

Can someone please lead me in the right direction on how I would do that?

[image]

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is another smart tip to do this. When we enter a custom number format, we can set two distinct formats for positive and negative values, separated with a semi-colon.

A significant advantage of this approach is we don't "loose" the number format: unlike a computed column, it is still recognized as a number if the report is exported to Excel, for example.

In the example below we set a negative format with brackets. If decimals are facultative we can use:

```
#0.##;(#0.##)
```

[image]

Comment: You can also make it fixed. In the options for a fixed number it allows you to have the format I desired

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any negative numbers in my data, but one option is to use a computed column in your data set

```
 if (row["Risk"] < 3){
 "(" +row["Risk"] + ")"
 }else { row["Risk"]}
```

I have a number between 1 and 4 in the row "Risk"

Results

```
(2)
(2)
3
4
(1)
3
(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add also add the number without brackets by Formatting the number as a Custom Number with Format Code: #,##0.00;#,###.00

[Example screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57ypk.png)